# What do we do with questions that link to a site for "help"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

I've seen a lot of new users coming in to Stackoverflow asking questions like "here's my site, how can I fix this issue?"  The problem with these questions, as I see it, is that future users of the site won't be able to see the issue that was originally asked in the question, which means the answers may or may not be viable for that future user.

Should we tailor our answers to better elaborate WHY the issue existed, create jsfiddle.net examples for those questions (and edit the question to include the link), vote to close the question, or flag it for moderator attention as too localized?

Comment: Close as too localized unless the OP can produce an SSCE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Politely request a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/). The link itself is too localized because (presumably) they'll eventually get their answer and fix the problem. At least they should link a JS Fiddle/Pastepin/ect that works and won't go away, but ideally you should have the problematic code in a short code block *in the body of your post*.

If the question is abandoned (very old, link no longer works/shows the issue, user hasn't been around forever) I'd just Vote to Close/flag as well, because it's very unlikely their old, maybe solved problem is going to be helpful to anyone with no example of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the actual issue is described in detail and some code as to where the problem is occurring is provided, a website example is perfectly acceptable for a visual example of the problem. The visual example is **for us to help you**. More than likely, visitors having that problem in the future **already know what it looks like**. They're having that problem, so *another* visual example is not really helpful to them.

If they're *only* posting a link to their website, then yes, that's a problem. Some sort of description and code should be included to help identify the problem here on the site so that future visitors can compare the problem to the one they're having.

As to the answers, yes. Explaining *why* the issue existed is always a plus, and I've been known to comment on answers requesting details when all they do is provide the solution. Sometimes I even explain why in my own answer (if I have the time).